# Want to know space consuming by logs

Tags: linux

I want to configure my application logs to splunk interface for easy referring.
Here i need to provide with how much of amount does my log files are consuming to splunk admins. As i can see my log files are saved from more than 6 months, here i would like to calculate how much amount of memory log files are consuming per day.
Do any of you have any idea how to calculate this

If my question is not clear please feel free to ask me.

Comment: Have you already consulted `du`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the current 6 month total, divide it by 183 days to get your daily usage.

Make sure to consider the uncompressed size.  So if your log files are compressed, you should copy them to a temporary location and uncompress them to get the correct size.